# Get myCustom.config as a JSON object

Tags: asp.net, javascript, json, configuration

I have a fair sized config file in my ASP.NET application that I would like to have access to in my client-side script.  Can anyone think of a good way to cause a section of my configuration to be serialized out as JSON and made available as a cacheable URL? This is .NET 3.5 and the config doesn't have any security issues.

Comment: Isn't IIS going to stop direct HTTP GET requests to the config file?

Comment: yup, but I don't want the config file, I want a JSON object representation of a certain section of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your referring to the web.config I'm certain you cannot access it via URL.  This is a native ASP.Net security feature.  You would want to create a custom config in a secure location and read/update it via AJAX using a server-side mechanism such as an IHttpHandler.

Comment: IHttpHandler would seem to be the right approach, especially as I use something similar to get my compressed css.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried this approach but I am sure you will find it useful. You can use T4 Templates to build a class dynamically from the config sections. This means anytime you change anything in that config section it will be picked up by the T4 templates and available for use in intellisense.

For a brief introduction on T4 templates check out the following URL:

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/557_Code_Generation_Using_T4_Templates.aspx

Comment: I understand the T4 concept, and thought about using it.  Do you know anyone successfully using T4?

Comment: Yes, in the above link I have created entity classes based on the database. Check out the link above!